# what does the word "infringing" mean in this context? all i found is somthing about copy rights and that doesnt make sense

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Problems like climate change, marine fisheries, and pollution grow worse, and global environmental surprises become common. Communities slowly realize that they cannot manage their local areas because global problems are **infringing**, and they begin to develop networks among communities, regions, and even nations to better
manage the global commons.

Comment: It's an incorrect usage. The writer probably got ***infringing*** muddled up with ***impinging*** and/or ***encroaching***.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the misuse of a word

Comment: i highly doubt it as it's part of "The Millennium Ecosystem Assesment". but you might be right and then it's just really furstrating..

Comment: i think "to encroach upon" solves the probelm. thanks alot!

Comment: The *meaning* is obvious, but I think you'd have to search a long time to find many (if any) more examples of this *specific* (intransitive) usage. It's not exactly a "serious" error, and it most likely arose because the text was probably translated from another language anyway. But it's certainly not "normal use of English" today, and I don't think it ever was.

Answer (score 0):

[Infringe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infringe) (MW)

See the description of synonyms and the discussion for English-language learners.

> to encroach upon
>
> to wrongly limit or restrict

It is used a lot in the sense of encroaching upon someone's intellectual property rights ("patent infringement"), but the more general sense of intruding, encroaching, or restricting is perfectly valid.

Comment: The full OED does actually include a definition for the "intransitiive" use *(to break in or encroach **on** or **upon**)*, but their last citation is 1868, and I certainly don't think any competent speaker today would use it without a preposition (introducing the associated object being encroached upon).

Comment: In the example sentence I see "local areas" implied as the thing being encroached upon.  It would read better to have "infringing *on them*" in there, I agree.

Comment: *Problems* don't "infringe" - it's something *lawbreakers* (such as copyright violators) do.